# Append to json file if ID does not exist else change values of existing ID

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a script that scrapes the web and collects some URLs. I want to collect the URLs in a json file with the following structure:

```
{
    "IDs": {
        "ID_0001": {
            "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
            "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
            "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
            "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
        },
        "ID_0002": {
            "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
            "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
            "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
            "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
        }
    }
}
```

The URLs for each ID could change over time and I only need the latest URLs for each ID. In addition to that the number of URLs could vary for each ID. Therefore I tried to create a function that takes a dictionary of the collected URLs and the ID, checks if the ID already exists in the json, and changes the values accordingly.
But if the json file does not contain the ID the function should append the data.

Take those two examples:

```
ID_0002
{
 "url_1": "http://www.url_1.com",
 "url_2": "http://www.url_2.com",
 "url_3": "http://www.url_3.com",
 "url_4": "http://www.url_4.com"
}
```

```
ID_0003
{
 "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
 "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
 "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
 "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
}
```

After running the function once for each example the new json file should contain updated values for `ID_0002` (URLs now with underscores) and an appended entry for `ID_0003`. Like this:

```
{
    "IDs": {
        "ID_0001": {
            "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
            "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
            "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
            "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
        },
        "ID_0002": {
            "url_1": "http://www.url_1.com",
            "url_2": "http://www.url_2.com",
            "url_3": "http://www.url_3.com",
            "url_4": "http://www.url_4.com",
        },
        "ID_0003": {
            "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
            "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
            "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
            "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks to @Jonathan Leon my function now works and for anyone who needs it, it looks like this:

```
def load_dim_dict_to_json(dim_dict, ID):
    with open("test.json", "r+") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        data["IDs"][ID] = dim_dict
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, f)
        f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary can't have duplicate keys so you can just overwrite an existing ID's value with a new value, you don't have to check for it. Unless I'm missing something you can just read your file (which I called json_file) and use one line to replace or add new information.

```
json_file = {
    "IDs": {
        "ID_0001": {
            "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
            "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
            "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
            "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
        },
        "ID_0002": {
            "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
            "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
            "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
            "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
        }
    }
}
print(json_file['IDs'].keys())
>>>dict_keys(['ID_0001', 'ID_0002'])


id = 'ID_0002'
dic = {
 "url_1": "http://www.url_1.com",
 "url_2": "http://www.url_2.com",
 "url_3": "http://www.url_3.com",
 "url_4": "http://www.url_4.com"
}

json_file['IDs'][id] = dic
print(json_file['IDs'].keys())
>>>dict_keys(['ID_0001', 'ID_0002']) # same keys
#Updated data for ID_0002

{'IDs': {'ID_0001': {'url_1': 'http://www.url1.com',
   'url_2': 'http://www.url2.com',
   'url_3': 'http://www.url3.com',
   'url_4': 'http://www.url4.com'},
  'ID_0002': {'url_1': 'http://www.url_1.com',
   'url_2': 'http://www.url_2.com',
   'url_3': 'http://www.url_3.com',
   'url_4': 'http://www.url_4.com'}}}

id = 'ID_0003'
dic = {
 "url_1": "http://www.url1.com",
 "url_2": "http://www.url2.com",
 "url_3": "http://www.url3.com",
 "url_4": "http://www.url4.com",
}

json_file['IDs'][id] = dic
print(json_file['IDs'].keys())
>>>dict_keys(['ID_0001', 'ID_0002', 'ID_0003']) #added new key

# new key added
{'IDs': {'ID_0001': {'url_1': 'http://www.url1.com',
   'url_2': 'http://www.url2.com',
   'url_3': 'http://www.url3.com',
   'url_4': 'http://www.url4.com'},
  'ID_0002': {'url_1': 'http://www.url_1.com',
   'url_2': 'http://www.url_2.com',
   'url_3': 'http://www.url_3.com',
   'url_4': 'http://www.url_4.com'},
  'ID_0003': {'url_1': 'http://www.url1.com',
   'url_2': 'http://www.url2.com',
   'url_3': 'http://www.url3.com',
   'url_4': 'http://www.url4.com'}}}
```